# StaticCompiler - Run the same application few time in one html page

Tags: dsl, haxe, hexmachina

I'm looking for a solution to allow running multiple time the same compiled DSL in one HTML page.

For now, I use XMLReader and change with preprocessors at runtime the context name. But StaticCompiler is more powerfull.

The problem with StaticCompiler, we have to set context name as a constant at compiletime, and the context name is used as a classpath and couldn't be edited at runtime without breaking everything.

Is a solution to sandboxing application with StaticCompiler?

Related issues : https://github.com/DoclerLabs/hexMachina/issues/214

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is support with hexmachina 0.28.0 : https://github.com/DoclerLabs/hexMachina/releases/tag/0.28.0

```
var code = StaticFlowCompiler.compile( assembler, "context/flow/dsl.flow" );
code.execute();

var clonedCode = code.clone( new ApplicationAssembler() );
clonedCode.execute();

Assert.isInstanceOf( code.locator.instance, MockClassWithoutArgument );
Assert.isInstanceOf( clonedCode.locator.instance, MockClassWithoutArgument );

Assert.notEquals( code.locator.instance, clonedCode.locator.instance );
```